# How to deploy Angular8 SSR to Ec2 with Nginx?

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, universal

I have created angular8 app and for SEO I have used angular universal which works fine on localhost but whenever deploy on ec2 it's not working

I used

> ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject angular-universal-app

this to create SEO friendly which works on http://localhost:4000 but when ever i deploy Live its not working

This is my server file

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

import * as express from 'express';
import {join} from 'path';
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 443;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/browser');
const {AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP, ngExpressEngine, provideModuleMap} = require('./dist/server/main');


app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', DIST_FOLDER);
app.get('*.*', express.static(DIST_FOLDER, {
  maxAge: '1y'
}));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req });
});
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

Want SEO on Live